# How to disable the first http request if the second request to the server doesn't work?

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I'm building shop app using flutter that i let the user to place an order this order will be placed in two folders in the database one under the seller to know that he has new order and one under the user folder to know his upcoming order, i'm implementing these two http request in one function when the user place an order, i was wondering if the second request doesn't succeed for example due to internet connection i want to disable the first http request because the data in the database will be wrong in this way! so how to solve like this issue?

Comment: Most probably the solution for this is to move the logic to the backend with one HTTP request only and then open/close a transaction.

Comment: @lespch is right, this is the job of a database transaction, ensuring several records are made, or 0, never only 1. And it means the logic has to be done on the backend with 1 entrypoint in the backend managing the transaction, you do not want to rethink transactions from the front (think concurrency, parallelism, etc. it's a mess).

Comment: @regilero  thanks for your response, so what should i do that i should tell the backend developer that works with php and tells him that this api should do these two works at the same time with one http request, and what i'm expecting from him to return is either done or error, right ?